# wordpress htaccess in sub folder not redirecting to https

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, https

I have a domain with a working htaccess file, which redirects all http traffic to https. This is/was working all fine.

Here is that .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.well-known/acme-challenge
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Just now, **I have installed wordpress** in a sub-folder called "blogg" like this:

> www.example.com/blogg/

I noticed right away that the blog was not https. So I went to wordpress admin and changed the URL in general settings from "http" to "https". This seems to have made all links in wordpress, as well as the admin page, use https.

Unfortunately it didnt help when going to the blogg in the web browser, it is still http, although https works if I enter it manually in the browser.

Here is the htaccess file in the wordpress directory (example.com/blogg/.htaccess):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blogg/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blogg/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I am new to .htaccess, and would like some help in finding the right code for all my domain to be https, including the blog. Help is appreciated.
To be clear, I want all http requests to automatically go to https instead.

I have tried adding this line in the second .htaccess file: (no luck though).

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off RewriteRule ^(.*)$
  https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

BR

Comment: You should do a find/replace in your database, and search for `http://yoursite.com` and replace with `https://yoursite.com` There are several plugins available that can do this.  Once you do that, it will most likely work as you expect, without using custom rewrite rules in .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blogg/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blogg/index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]    //SERVER_NAME = your actual domain name for WP
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

You can also look into this code since its an easier version. It will give you idea about WP htaccess if in root folder as well. :)

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Not working.RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L] - This line redirects to the main site "https://www.example.com.
So for instance, http://www.example.com/blog/ redirects to https://www.example.com

Comment: Yes, you need to replace that with the actual url which is till your sub directory. If you are still facing issue in writing the custom htaccess, best you use a simple plugin like "Really Simple SSL". It will do the job for you. Just install in your blog/ wp and follow the steps. That's it.